# Standard way to store site key, forgot-password questions in LDAP?

Tags: authentication, ldap

Is there a standard way to store a (reference to a) site key image, or forgot-password security questions in LDAP?  Or are these better stored in a database?

Should I take the desire for these features as a sign that LDAP isn't a good fit for my usage patterns in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

eDirectory has these features built in.
I do not believe any other LDAP server vendor has any method.

We like: http://code.google.com/p/pwm/
Which will work with most LDAP implementations with a little work.

-jim